# moment utc, does date-fns have something similar?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs, date-fns

I'm currently refactoring a large codebase that are using moment for dates.
There are lots of places where the date in gotten like: `moment.utc()`

I cant seem to find something like it in `date-fns`? Does anyone know how I get the same functionality in `date-fns`? or just plain vanilla?

Just has to match the same as `moment.utc()`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Objects provided by the Moment.js library have the concept of "modes".  A `moment` object can be in local mode, utc mode, or be fixed to a particular time zone offset.  It can also belong to a named time zone via the moment-timezone add-on library.  When you call `moment.utc()`, you are setting the moment object to UTC mode.

Date-fns is an excellent library that provides helper functions that work with the `Date` standard object provided by the JavaScript language (in the ECMAScript standard).  Thus, its functions are limited to what you can do with a `Date` object.

The `Date` object does not have modes in the way that moment does.  Thus, you cannot switch a `Date` object to UTC mode using Date-fns or any other vanilla js technique.

The `Date` object always tracks a UTC point in time internally, and it exposes some functions and parameters that take UTC time, and others that take local time.  Any that use local time are converting/to from UTC at the time of the function call.  In other words, if you call `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)`, those values are in local time, and they are converted immediately to UTC.  You can get the internal value at any time by calling `.getTime()` or `.valueOf()`.  If you want a more common representation, `.toISOString()` is a great option.

In conclusion: You can't convert a `Date` object to UTC because it is *already* in UTC.  You can only ask for UTC or local time output, based on the functions you call.